# What is the difference between MYSITE, INTRANET and SSPADMIN webapplications in Sharepoint-2007?

Tags: workflow, team-sites

I am new to Sharepoint and want to create a new Team Site.
I would like to setup a 3-State workflow and create 3 users who are involved in this worflow.

Under which webapplication should I create the new Teamsite:

1. sspadmin
2. intranet
3. mysite

Answer (score 2):

The names of the web applications don't have to be the same for any MOSS farm. 
In your case guessing from their names SSPADMIN is used for SP Shared Sevices Provider, MYSITE is used to host the users MySite and INTRANET is for other SP sites (Team sites, Meeting, etc.)

Create a site collection on INTRANET and work on its top level site or create subsites.